# How to give NDK/Native code same file permissions as Java?

Tags: android, android-ndk

My app is letting users select audio files with an `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` from within their document hierarchy (ordinarily on internal storage and not in my app's storage). The files, once selected, are then processed natively in OBOE.

I have JNI working. I can open the file in java and copy the bytecode over to native.

But if I want to open a file directly in the Native code then I must set the app to `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`. This seems a bit clumsy, it is probably because I'm sending the file path - using `getPath()` on the `uri` - to native and using `fopen()`?

Is it possible for me to inherit the permission from the java side to open the file natively without requiring All Files Acess permission? I tried sending a FileDescriptor over but that wasn't successful, although could have been my implementation.

Comment: "it is probably because I'm sending the file path to native and using fopen()?" -- there is no file path. "from within their document hierarchy (ordinarily on internal storage and not in my app's storage)" -- the content is not necessarily on internal storage, let alone in a location that you can access via the filesystem. The content could be in Google Drive, or on an SMB/CIFS fileserver, or in an encrypted data store, or handled via a countless number of other document provider implementations.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, sure, it *could* be but anyone using my app will be accessing an audio file that is on the device. That seems irrelevant, the question remains how can I open the file natively with the same permissions as the provider on the javaside?

Comment: "but anyone using my app will be accessing an audio file that is on the device" -- how were you planning on forcing that? "I'm sending the file path - using getPath() on the uri" -- that is only valid if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. You are not going to get such a `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` directly. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` will give you a `Uri` with a `content` scheme, and for those the `Uri` overall is an opaque identifier.